# pin subviews to leading and trailing edges of stackview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have label1 and label2.

My stackview's axis is horizontal.

I want to pin label1 to the left and pin label2 to the far right. Similar to:

```
|label1-------------------label2|
```

I know I can change label2's `textAlignment` to `right` but I was wondering if there is a pure stackview way of doing it (so I could use this for any other non-UILabel layouts)? I tried all kinds of `distribution` but non worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
```

works just fine.

Not sure what I was doing wrong before...